# What is the advantage to starting your meld and laying it down when it isn't complete? Why not just wait until you have all seven?

Tags: hand-and-foot

What is the advantage to starting your meld and laying it down when it isn't complete? Why not just wait until you have all seven?

Answer (score 2):

If you have four cards to meld in your hand, and if you don't play them, then how is your partner going to add the three cards he potentially has in his hand?

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing teams you benefit your team by melding with three cards. If playing singles, which in my experience is much more fun and competitive, holding your cards as long as possible keeps other players from knowing what you are collecting.